# How to add nil value to Modal Class in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

My Modal Class:

```
class eventsModelClass: NSObject {    

    var eveName: String = ""
    var eveVenue: String = ""

    override init() {
    }

    init(name : String) {
        self.eveName = name
    }

    init(venue : String) {
        self.eveVenue = venue
    }
}
```

My MainViewController:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    var MyClass = eventsModelClass()

   MyClass.eveName = "Dinner"
   MyClass.eveVenue = "Hotel"
}
```

In this main class, if I load the `eveName` and `eveVenue` directly, it is working fine. But I am using Parse details to load 100 events and venue. So there are chances that there may be nil value in it. So I wonder how can I tell MyClass that this value is nil, so keep it as empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I wonder how can I tell MyClass that this value is nil, so keep it as empty?

The way you've set things up, you cannot. A String variable cannot be `nil`.

However, if you declare your properties as `String?` instead of `String` — an Optional wrapping a String — now they can be `nil`. That is one of the main purposes of Optionals. One nice thing about this is that such a property will in fact be `nil` *by default*; unlike any other kind of value in Swift, it is initialized automatically if you don't initialize it explicitly.

Remember, however, that now whenever you deal with this property, you will need to unwrap it safely. You can't use an Optional for much without unwrapping it, and unwrapping `nil` will crash your program.

Comment: To learn more about Optionals, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_optional

Comment: Ok, so if I set the value as `String?` it will be stored as nil and when I retrieve and unwrap it, it will be nil?

Comment: Not the value. The type. And when you retrieve it, you will _not_ unwrap it. You will just look to see if it is `nil`. Please, read the link I gave you. It's all there. This is basic stuff; you should not have to ask about it.